Why are MySql error messages nondescriptive and/or wrong?
I lose a lot of time with MySql error-messages that are nondescriptive ("You have an error in your syntax") or just plainly wrong. Today, I made the following mistake:
SELECT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM setting WHERE name = `radioID`)

My bad: I used ticks ` instead of single quotes '. But here is the error message I get when I run this MySql command via Python on a Raspberry:
An error occurred: 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'radioID' in 'where clause'

This error message is just plainly wrong.
Error messages in PHP, Python or Java seem much better. They point the programmer in the right direction. But in my experience MySql error messages are worthless: if anything, they point in the wrong direction.
Why is that? Is it somehow harder to generate good error messages in MySql?

Backtics are used to select identifiers thus it's expected to encounter this error.

More of a rant than a question...

if you are just reading the "You have an error in your syntax" part, you aren't going to get much from that.  the key is that it always shows you the first thing it couldn't figure out what to do with after that preface (which is sometimes the end of the query, so an empty string).  not getting helped by the syntax error is almost always a case of not actually reading the whole message and looking at your query to figure out what went wrong, then sometimes consulting the manual to compare your syntax to correct syntax.  if you do that, it is almost always very helpful.

The error message is completely descriptive. That's you who have not analyzed the error message which results in you have not understood the problem.
The error message tells that it treates radioID as a column name whereas you want it to be a literal. There is only one place in the query text where this value is used. And it is obvious that you have used incorrect quoting, you have used backtick instead of single quote char.
PS. MySQL/MariaDB have the best error messages system, the error message is well-descriptive in most cases. I know only one situation when the error message does not match the error - this is an error message which is generated when you use FULL JOIN which is not implemented.

How about the note "table does not support optimize" when one runs OPTIMIZE TABLE on an InnoDB table, and yet it does support optimize. :-)

Also this old one, which has since been fixed: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=94396

@BillKarwin I don't understand... the table supports OPTIMIZE but the attempt to execute it produces an error with shown message text? if so then why do you think that the table supports OPTIMIZE (maybe now, maybe at all)?

See https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=108101 for my bug report on that, and response from the MySQL team (which I disagree with).

@BillKarwin Oh, I see.. This is a note, not an error message. And I agree with you, MySQL support team's arguments don't seem convincing to me too.
